# Netbeans for remote system development - PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I have been using Eclipse for Remote System Development and after hearing a lot of good things about Netbeans for PHP development, I wanted to give it a shot.

I ran into couple of issues even before starting:

**1. Downloading complete remote directory to my local machine:**

I work on multiple projects located on a development server and the code base is pretty huge. While setting up new PHP remote project using sftp to access my remote directories, Netbeans started downloading all the files from the remote location I specified. This is a bit annoying  as it is taking really long to download all the files (includes large videos which are part of the projects).

Eclipse remote system development (and most other editors like EditPlus), on the other hand, simply shows me the remote file structure and only downloads a file to local temp dir when I open it.

Is this behavior standard in Netbeans?

**2. Will external file modifications cause sync issues?**

I usually update my svn by connecting to the dev server using putty. Since Netbeans is trying to maintain a copy of it's own on my local computer, will updating the source files externally outside netbeans create sync issues?

**3. Can I manage remote svn repos from within Netbeans?**

Since I already checked-out my svn projects on the dev server, can I use svn from within netbeans to commit or update?

Comment: Version control (CVS, SVN, Git) software is made for this kind of stuff, and Netbeans supports all the aforementioned version control packages.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is standard. Netbeans downloads the remote application so that it can scan the local copies to enable code-completion.
2. It shouldn't. By default, Netbeans is almost immediately aware of any changes you make to project files outside of Netbeans.
3. Yes.

Comment: downloading all the files is frustating especially when I want to develop in a new local machine. Is there a way to just edit the remote sources direclty?

Comment: Netbeans is a project-based editor. Everything must be in a project. It isn't designed to work with individual files. If you just want to edit files on a remote server then you're better off just using a text editor like EditPlus or Vim since you can't get any of the advantages of using Netbeans (e.g. code completion) without it scanning all of your source files.

Comment: Coda 2 allow you to edit directly on the server with an FTP connection, but you lost smart PHP autocompletation.